# Download multi file by HttpHandler

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms, httphandler

In my app,user can download own files(image,pdf,word,...).I use HttpHandel for do it.Beginning select the file and download.I want that user can doawnload all file from list.How do this?
[image]

```
 public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) {

        HttpResponse response = context.Response;
        string cururl = context.Request.Url.ToString();
        int iqs = context.Request.Url.ToString().IndexOf('?');
        string querystring = (iqs < cururl.Length - 1) ? cururl.Substring(iqs + 1) : String.Empty;
        NameValueCollection parameters = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(querystring);
        byte[] result = GetstreamForDownload(parameters);
        string fileId = context.Request.QueryString["fileId"];
        response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + GetFileName(parameters));
        response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        response.BinaryWrite(result);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `GetstreamForDownload()` method should return all files, for example in a Zip archive, when the `parameters` contain certain key-value pairs you select, for example `?folderId=123&allFiles=true`.

Comment: GetstreamForDownload() return binary  data and  response.BinaryWrite() send binary to client for download.How to zip binary for all files?